# Convert all lowercase letters to their corresponding smallcaps equivalents

Tags: php, text, replace, fonts

When trying to convert all letters in a string from lowercase to smallcaps ([Unicode characters representing capital letters at the height of lowercase letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps)), is there an easier way to do this than running str_replace once each for every letter of the alphabet?

My String

```
$my_str = 'there has to be an easier way than this mess';
```

The Lengthy Process

```
//Replace Values from my_str
$my_str = str_replace("a", "ᴀ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("b", "ʙ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("c", "ᴄ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("d", "ᴅ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("e", "ᴇ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("f", "ғ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("g", "ɢ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("h", "ʜ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("i", "ɪ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("j", "ᴊ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("k", "ᴋ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("l", "ʟ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("m", "ᴍ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("n", "ɴ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("o", "ᴏ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("p", "ᴘ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("q", "ᴏ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("r", "ʀ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("s", "s", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("t", "ᴛ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("u", "ᴜ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("v", "ᴠ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("w", "ᴡ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("x", "x", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("y", "ʏ", $my_str);
$my_str = str_replace("z", "ᴢ", $my_str);
```

Then to display

```
// Display replaced string
echo $my_str
```

Output (It works but seems messy and poorly coded)

```
ᴛʜᴇʀᴇ ʜᴀs ᴛᴏ ʙᴇ ᴀɴ ᴇᴀsɪᴇʀ ᴡᴀʏ ᴛʜᴀɴ ᴛʜɪs ᴍᴇss
```

Outcome

I was seeing if there was a way to improve the code. As it seems messy and there is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: Please define what your goal is. Maybe https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php, question is unclear (Y an Z don't look like standard characters).

Comment: I was seeing if there was a way to improve the code. As it seems messy and there is probably a better way to do it. The outcome is to make normal text generate as small caps which it does but there could be a better way to do it

Comment: Define the expected behavior of the code. Is it just suppose to capitalize letters, are those special chars? Does the code not work or you just want a one liner?

Comment: the code works. It's meant to replace a-z to small caps but i thought there might of been a better way to do it than i have shown.

Comment: Would using `strtoupper()` and then styling the font-size achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: Actually DannyXCII that is a good shout. Ill try that.

Comment: I've submitted an edit to explain what small caps is. Both DannyXCII and user3783243 seem to be confused with that word.

If you really need those characters the easiest way is to use arrays in a single str_replace as suggested in my other answer. Another option would be to transform the characters by shifting the codepoint numbers for each letter to the space where smallcaps are defined.

Comment: The second option is however beyond what I can remember from the top of my head. You'd have to consult the PHP documentation for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually need those strange unicode characters, you could at least improve your code by using a single str_replace with two arrays for the search and replace characters.

```
$my_str = str_replace(
  array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",),
  array("ᴀ","ʙ","ᴄ","ᴅ","ᴇ","ғ","ɢ","ʜ","ɪ","ᴊ","ᴋ","ʟ","ᴍ","ɴ","ᴏ","ᴘ","ᴏ","ʀ","s","ᴛ","ᴜ","ᴠ","ᴡ","x","ʏ","ᴢ",),
  $my_str
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the outcome you are looking for, without the use of non-standard characters, you can use the `strtoupper()` function and style the resulting output:

```php
<?php

$string = "Here is some text!";

$string = strtoupper( $string );

?>

<p><?= $string; ?></p>
```

```css
p {
  font-size: .8rem;
}
```